# Why this for-loop is skipped?

Tags: java

In the following Java code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Integer[] k = new Integer[] {0, 1, 2, 3};

    int m = 0;
    while (m < k.length) {
        for (int i = 0; i < k.length && k[i] != null; i++)
            System.out.print(k[i] + " ");
        System.out.println("");
        k[m++] = null;
    }
}
```

I was trying to get the following output:

```
0 1 2 3
1 2 3
2 3
3
```

However, the inner for-loop is skipped altogether after the first pass, that is, after the 0 1 2 3 output, and it's because the first element was set to null after the first pass, but I don't understand why that matters, can someone please explain? really confused. Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Do you know what the `k[i] != null` in the loop test means?

Comment: And ... do you know what `k[m++] = null` does?

Comment: I strongly recommend learning to use your debugger.

Comment: thanks, everyone, I see the problem now, I guess it was a brain-fart, thanks again for all your patience.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `i = m` instead of `i=0` then it will work.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Integer[] k =  new Integer[] {0, 1, 2, 3};

    int m = 0;
    while (m < k.length) {
        for (int i = m; i < k.length && k[i] != null; i++)
            System.out.print(k[i] + " ");
        System.out.println("");
        k[m++] = null;
    }
```

Comment: And you can remove `k[m++] = null;` (make it `m++`), and eliminate the `k[i] != null` test.

Comment: Yes of course, it is quite redundant in this case, I just wanted to keep the answer focused on his actual error.

Answer (score 1):

Try going through the code iteration-per-iteration and update the values:

Let's pretend we reached this line of code for the first time:

```
// Right now, (**before** the next line is executed), 
// `m` is still `0`, `k.length` is 4 (which is how we reached this point). 
// `i` is 0, which is less than `k.length`, and `k[i]` is `0`.

// This line sets `k[m]` to `null`, and then sets `m` to `m+1`.
k[m++] = null;   

// And now (**after** the above line is executed), `m` is 1, 
// `k.length` is still 4, so we get to go into the while loop for the second time. 
// At this point, `k: [null, 1, 2, 3]`.
```

In the while loop, we then encounter the inner-loop again, which (this is our **second** time on this line) is:

```
// ...in the while loop for the second time...
// Remember, the k array now looks like: k: [null, 1, 2, 3]
for (int i = 0; i < k.length && k[i] != null; i++)
```

Your condition fails at this point because:

```
// Evaluating: i < k.length && k[i] != null
i < k.length // i: 0, k.length: 4, this is true
k[i] != null // i: 0 here, and k[0]: `null`, so this is false

true && false // returns false -> Don't go in the inner for-loop
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. It was so obvious in hindsight, brain-fart indeed. Thank you again

Answer (score 0):

`i < k.length && k[i] != null` this makes the for-loop stop. Your index (`i`) starts at 0 so after you loop the first time you have the following scenario when looping the 2nd time:

```
k = {null, 1, 2, 3}
m = 1

m < k.length = true

i = 0
i < k.length = true

// k = {null, 1, 2, 3}
// i = 0
// k[i] = k[0] = null
k[i] != null = false
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you don't just use two `for` loops, it's a bit clearer:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Integer[] k = new Integer[] {0, 1, 2, 3};

    for (int m = 0; m < k.length; m++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < k.length && k[i] != null; i++) {
            System.out.print(k[i] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println("");
        k[m] = null;
    }
}
```

The problem statement being your inner loop, which checks if `k[i] != null`. The second statement of a `for` loop is a termination condition. If it returns `false`, the loop ends. In essence, you're attempting to not print values if they're null, but this will simply terminate your loop upon reaching a null value. Instead, check the condition of the element inside the inner loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < k.length; i++) {
    if (k[i] != null) {
        System.out.print(k[i] + " ");
    }
}
```

Additionally, you can even skip based on current index using this inner loop now (`int i = m`) instead of setting to null, so the second iteration is 1-3, and third is 2-3, etc. This additionally makes the null check/setting redundant, as well as allowing you to use `int[]`. Thus, the final solution looks like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] k = new int[] {0, 1, 2, 3};

    for (int m = 0; m < k.length; m++) {
        for (int i = m; i < k.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(k[i] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by these statements:

`k[i] != null;`

`k[m++] = null;`

If you set the next element in the array to be `null`, the null check condition in the `for` loop will fail and the loop will not execute.

Remove these two statements and do this:

```
class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int k[] = {0, 1, 2, 3};
        int m = 0;
        while (m < k.length) {
            for (int i = m; i < k.length; i++)
                System.out.print(k[i]);
            System.out.print("\n");
            m++;
        }
    }
}
```